# Set path on javascript file?

Tags: javascript

I want to set any path of url to javascript file like :

```
$ image_path = "http://siteurl.com/inc/"
```

How to put into my code below:

```
css({"background":"url(image/bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0"})
```

I want to put inside url become url(`image_path` + image/bg.png) so my url css become **http://siteurl.com/inc/image/bg.png**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate it into the string, like so:

```
var image_path = "http://siteurl.com/inc/"

element.css("background" , "url(" + image_path + "image/bg.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0");
```